# SSRS - Sort tablix based on result of Lookup

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to sort a tablix in SSRS based on the result of a Lookup?

This is my lookup:

```
=Lookup(Fields!AcctNumber.Value, Fields!AccountNumber.Value, "FOUND", "DetailsDataset")
```

Which populates a column with "FOUND" if the account number is found in the "DetailsDataset" and with nothing if it is not. Is it possible to get all of the "FOUND" entries to go to the bottom so only the ones not found are at the top?

I have tried putting my expression in the Sorting of both the Tablix Properties and the Group Properties but neither work. No other sorting is being done on either one.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work on the row group sorting. I tired this myself and it worked as expected....

He's a quick GIF to demo my test. The first run is with no sorting (although I started recording late so it's only visible for half a second...) so you can see the raw data, then I apply the sort expression and test again, and finally reverse the sort.

[image]

Comment: I tried this again since it's clearly working for you and discovered it works on some of my tables but not the ones I was initially testing this on. So at least I know that it works, I just have to figure out what is making it not work on the few it doesn't work on, which shouldn't be too hard by comparing them.


Thank you for the help!

Comment: I believe I figured out that it does not work when referencing a dataset that is being displayed above the current dataset. I'm not sure why this is or how to get around it besides creating an identical dataset below it and hiding it (which did work but seems like bad practice). Any ideas?

Comment: I can't understand why that would make any difference, but in the past I've had odd behaviour (usually with the order of parameters) and recreating the report seems to fix it. If the report is not complex, it might be worth a try as the order of datasets should not make any difference.